# Javascript widget output by function

Tags: javascript, function, class, output

I have a js widget which gives me an output of a chart anywhere i place it.
But how can i control the output by using a function to place it or overwrite it with toher options?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<div> <h3>My Chart</h3>
<div class="chart" id="one">
<script type="text/javascript">
      new TradingView.widget({
      "width": 800,
      "height": 350,
      "symbol": "FX:EURUSD" 
    });
    </script></div></div>
```

Comment: You need to check the documentation of the widget, see if it takes an argument with the ID of a DIV to place the output, instead of outputting it in the location of the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `container_id` property inside the widget function then attach it to a div anywhere you want to place.

// script:

```
new TradingView.widget({
      'container_id': 'technical-analysis',
      'autosize': true,
      'symbol': "FX:EURUSD"          
    });
```

// html:

```
<div id="technical-analysis" style="width: 800px; height: 350px"></div>
```

Change width and height of the container div, and set `autosize` property inside the widget, the chart will fit perfectly the specified size within the container div.